# Troubleshooting a bad download speed on great Internet connection

Tags: networking, download, internet-connection, vlan, wan

I have a couple machines experiencing an awful download speed on an awesome Internet connection, and for the life of me I can't come up with a rational explanation as to why.

Speed test to the local ISP shows `>10Mbps downspeed`. The line is supposed to be symmetrical but test shows `~7Mbps upspeed`. Speed test to a server further away shows < 8Mbps. (One server I tested showed under 1Mbps.) And pingtest.net shows `11ms ping, 1ms jitter, 0% packet loss`. Internal pings are 1ms or 2ms.

Actual downloads however are terribly slow. The speeds vary between website. Drivers from `Dell (over FTP) at 40Kb/s`, sometimes 10Kb/s. Windows 8 Preview from `Microsoft 100Kb/s`, VLC from `SourceForge at 60Kb/s`.

**Firewall blocks all ICMP.** (This is clearly the problem, but this question is about to be closed so I won't get a chance to confirm what specifically the problem is in this case.)

Comment: can you provide some evidence ? pings, trace routes to different places etc. Not a lot to go on.

Comment: Your ISP hates you ;)

Comment: Are these D/L's done through torrents?  Is there a chance your ISP has throttled the ports that the clients use?

Comment: @Everett Download is straight from Dell. Also tried downloading Win8 preview from Microsoft, also very slow (100kbps). No torrents.

Comment: What does [pingtest.net](http://pingtest.net) say about your connection?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing Mbps with MB/s?

Comment: @David Schwartz Very sure. Either way a 10Mbps connection should get more than 100KBps, misunderstanding the difference doesn't skew the math *that* much.

Comment: @DarthAndroid pingtest.net shows 11ms ping, 1ms jitter, 0% packet loss.

Comment: Try a few other sites. Some places do put throttles on a per-client basis. But still, hours for 100Mb is not usual. Also, has this connection ever been faster, or is it new ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocking ICMP will cause horrible TCP performance problems because ICMP is used to perform [path MTU discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery). Remove the ICMP block and test again. I bet you'll find the problem goes away.

There are also other possible ways the firewall could be causing this. So I'd suggest shutting off the firewall and re-testing. If that solves the problem, enable the firewall but disable ICMP filtering and test again.

Comment: good shout. May well cause this.

Comment: Didn't have a chance to shut off the firewall entirely, but I did play around with serving files to one of the problem machines with a server using a lower MTU. This maxed out the connection on the server easily.

Comment: I would suggest going over all the settings on the firewall. If it was last worked on by someone who thought it was perfectly fine to block all ICMP (or managed to break path MTU some other way), I wouldn't trust any of its configuration.